# Python openpyxl TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pivotButton'

Tags: python

I get an error when trying to open the xlsx file (Excell 2010) with Python 3.4.3 & openpyxl 2.2.0. Is there any workaround to tesolve this issue ot this is a bug?

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:/TEMP/tfile.xlsx')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TEMP\py\pxl.py", line 3, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:/TEMP/tfile.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 149, in load_workbook
    _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, read_only, keep_vba)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 237, in _load_workbook
    keep_vba=keep_vba)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 324, in read_worksheet
    fast_parse(ws, xml_source, shared_strings, style_table, color_index)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 312, in fast_parse
    parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 93, in parse
    dispatcher[tag_name](element)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 189, in parse_row_dimensions
    self.parse_cell(cell)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 134, in parse_cell
    cell = Cell(self.ws, column, row, **style)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pivotButton'
```

Regards, Sergey

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue.  This is a bug in openpyxl that was fixed on March 24 2015, however the fix as of now has not been pushed to a release.

You can work around the issue by downgrading to openpyxl 2.1.5:

```
pip install openpyxl==2.1.5
```

See the [Bug Report](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/438/linux-version-of-openpyxl-does-not-open) for details.  You can also remove the pivot table from your excel file to work around the issue.

Comment: As of October 2016, version 2.3.5 seems to work fine.